# Quelle est la différence entre « potage » et « soupe » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, alimentation

J'ai l'impression que « potage » et « soupe » sont synonymes, mais il me semble que les synonymes ne sont jamais exactement équivalents.  Quelle est la différence entre les deux?

Le TLFi donne les définitions suivantes:

> Soupe: (définition B)
> Bouillon de légumes, de viandes, etc., généralement non passé et accompagné de pain ou de pâtes, que l'on sert au début du repas ou en plat unique.
>
> Potage:
> Préparation plus ou moins liquide d'aliments bouillis (légumes, viande, etc.), en morceaux ou passés, qui se sert habituellement chaude, additionnée ou non de pâtes, au début du dîner.

D'après ces définitions, il semblerait qu'un potage n'est jamais servi en plat unique et donc qu'une soupe n'est pas toujours un potage, mais que tout potage est une soupe.

Le [grand dictionnaire terminologique de l'OQLF](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/gdt.html), sous « [potage](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8432180) », a ceci à dire :

> ((Il ne faut pas confondre potage et soupe)). La soupe était autrefois additionnée de tranches de pain (certaines personnes le font encore) et elle est constituée d'aliments solides non passés et en morceaux généralement assez gros. Les soupes peuvent être à la bière, au lait ou au vin, mais elles sont habituellement préparées à l'eau : soupe à l'oignon, potée, soupe à l'ail, soupe au fromage, etc. Elles ont comme élément de base des viandes, des poissons ou des légumes secs, ou frais en morceaux (ou un mélange des deux), ces derniers parfois additionnés de pâtes ou de riz, ce qui, dans tous les cas, donne un aliment consistant : soupe à l'écossaise, soupe au poulet, soupe de poisson, chaudrée de palourdes, soupe au chou, soupe minestrone, soupe au pistou, etc. Les soupes ont encore ceci de particulier qu'elles sont le plus souvent versées sur du pain émincé, séché ou non, ou garnies de produits de biscotterie.

Est-ce une différence universellement reconnue ?

Comment: La soupe est un type de potage.

Comment: @Knu: peux-tu donner une référence ou bien esquisser un peu plus la nuance?  que caractérise les potages qui ne sont pas des soupes? EDIT: je viens de regarder dans le grand dictionaire de l'OQLF.  Je vais rajouter leur commentaire au texte de ma question.

Comment: Bin ça me donne faim, cette histoire de brouets.

Comment: Et le velouté dans tout ça?

Comment: Je pense qu'on peut dire "soupe" comme "broth" en anglais, mais "potage" resemble plus comme "thick soup" en anglais

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On raconte ...

[à l'époque des bureaux scolaires percés d'un trou pour recevoir l'encrier dans lequel l'élève en sarrau gris ou bleu trempait une plume à facette « Sergent Major »]

... que le bouillon (plus ou moins gras, avec quelques légumes, parfois de la charcuterie, mais sans viande) que l'on versait sur l'épaisse tranche de pain (souvent rassis car cuit une fois par semaine dans les fours banaux), formaient la soupe.

Le pain mangé, une rasade de vin ajoutée aux restes du bouillon faisait chabrot.

L'assiette ensuite retournée servait parfois de support au fromage, que l'on dégustait à la pointe d'un couteau qui servait aussi à couper le pain dur en morceau (les déficiences des dentures ne permettant pas d'y « mordre à pleine dent »).

Lorsque la saison s'y prêtait un fruit terminait le repas des plus aisés.

Pendant ce temps, nobliaux et bourgeois s'ouvraient l'appétit d'un potage délicatement préparé par les meilleurs cuisiniers (plutôt cuisinières dans les maisons bourgeoises).

La soupe a une histoire populaire, le potage des recettes culinaires.

On peut « cracher dans la soupe de quelqu'un » pour déclencher une bagarre ou des rancunes tenaces.
On soufflettera ou on provoquera en duel un consommateur de potage.

Le pain qui représentaient 80% des apports énergétiques avant la révolution s'est vu complété par la pomme de terre par la suite.
Mais il est resté indissociable de la soupe : 
« Être trempé comme une soupe » fait référence à l'état du pain dans son bouillon.

Mis à part l'expression « *[Y-a une ... dans le potage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11844/quest-ce-quon-entend-par-une-couille-dans-le-potage-c-est-une-erreur-deux)* » qui par vulgarité est sensé perturber le bon déroulement d'une dégustation élégante, y a-t-il de telle référence au potage ?

Après la dernière guerre mondiale, les aides de la Politique Agricole Commune PAC, l'accroissement des rendements et des surfaces exploitées mécaniquement a entraîné la diminution du nombre d'agriculteurs que l'on a retrouvés ouvriers dans l'industrie, sans jardin potager.
L'influence de la soupe ira en diminuant au profit de la frite en particulier (moins chère à l'achat), puis de l'alimentation vendue toute préparée.

À tel point que le pain est vendu en croûtons séparés de la brique de soupe.

*La soupe populaire* (et non *Le potage populaire*) indique une résurgence d'un plat unique et roboratif composé d'un bouillon et de légumes accompagnés de pâtes, mais sans le pain originel.
En revanche rien n'interdit d'y tremper du pain et de saucer (récupérer les derniers aliments en essuyant l'assiette avec un bout de pain).

Lorsque l'on veut punir quelqu'un, on le met au pain sec et à l'eau, on le prive de la chaleur bienfaisante de la soupe, qui apporte une légère suée reposante après le dur labeur des champs.

La *panade* (Soupe faite avec de l'eau, du beurre et du pain qu'on a laissé mitonner – Émile Littré) indique un temps de vaches maigres : « Être dans la panade ».

Les définitions du Littré (téléchargeable ou consultable en ligne) reflètent plus des références culinaires interchangeables qu'un usage.

La soupe est très liée au pain que l'on ne jette pas mais que l'on transforme en pain perdu. Elle rappelle la seule nourriture accessible en période de disette ou de rationnement en tickets.

« Toto mange ta soupe » (*[Fernand Raynaud entre autre](https://www.ladissertation.com/Divers/Divers/Toto-Mange-Ta-Soupe-148650.html)*) est encore dans l'inconscient actuel d'un plat quasi unique, le potage reste une façon élégante de présenter une soupe décorée d'ingrédients raffinés qui sera accompagné d'autres mets succulents.

---

P.S. : *Le brouet*  [de *breu* : ancien français du XIII<sup>e</sup>, du germanique *brou*] est un plat composé d'ingrédients simples (comme de la viande de porc, du sang, du sel…) se présentant sous forme semi-liquide.
Il était consommé durant la période de la Grèce Antique, mais également au Moyen Âge (brouet de fèves par exemple). [Wikipédia]

C'est bien l'ancêtre du *bouillon* [de bouillir] dans lequel on a fait bouillir les ingrédients ; il a donc pour synonyme *bouillon* et *potage* pour le Robert.

- On trempe les aliments, on les 'détend' à l'aide d'une eau chaude parfumée, ce qui donne une *soupe* liquide, dans laquelle les ingrédients se ramollissent.
- On met à bouillir des aliments dans de l'eau qui réduit en s'évaporant, ce qui donne une consistance entre la soupe et la purée qui entoure les ingrédients plus solide pour le *brouet*, le *potage* a raffiné l'antique *brouet*.

Comment: La conclusion serait donc que «potage» est plus prétentieux que «soupe»?

Comment: Cela ressemble à une citation dont la source n'est pas donnée. Avez-vous vécu en ce temps là pour être si au courant? De plus cela ne répond pas du tout a la question. Ou peut-être un 'bot'.

Comment: Désolé, mais c'est tapé à la volée. Sources : lectures + rencontres + écoute, même un souvenir (années 60) pour ce qui concerne le fromage et la denture ; point et i au-dessus ne m'ont pas semblé nécessaires pour confirmer la question en restituant le contexte historique ; quant au 'bot' ..

Comment: Pourquoi le -1? cette réponse, bien qu'elle ne réponde qu'en partie à la question, m'aide à comprendre mieux les différences de connotation.  Je ne sais pas si ce sont les normes sur ce site stackexchange, mais je pense qu'il serait plus poli d'expliquer (de façon constructive) comment la réponse pourrait être améliorée quand on met un -1.

Comment: Remerciements à Sam Lisi - J'ai préféré compléter entre temps ma première version pour améliorer la vision des lecteurs hors hexagone, et je regrette (un peu) de m'être laissé déstabilisé en essayant de me justifier face à une une attitude non conforme à la nétiquette que vous venez de rappeler.

Comment: Oui, Vladtn, ressaisissez-vous, et même si vous n'aimez pas, ne *crachez pas dans la soupe* ! (Car nous sommes quelques uns à apprécier la prose de l'ami cl-r ;-) )

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Remise en place faite, merci :)

Answer (score 9):

Un potage est *toujours* plus raffiné qu'une soupe. On mange une soupe à la campagne, par exemple une soupe aux choux. Si tu veux recevoir des amis à diner un soir d'hiver, et si tu veux les impressionner par ton savoir-faire culinaire, là tu leur proposera un délicieux potage en entrée.

Pour résumer : la soupe est populaire, le potage est exquis.

Comment: Plus raffiné que le potage, il y a le consommé.

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord avec le dernier intervenant, à savoir que le bas-peuple mange de la soupe, la classe moyenne mange du potage et la haute société mange du consommé.

Comment: Je me suis abstenu d'un (+1), non que je sois réellement en désaccord avec le propos, mais ce *toujours* (avec emphase) est un peu excessif quand même. Je pense à la fameuse et **très** mondaine *Soupe à la tortue* du [Festin de Babette](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Festin_de_Babette), qui a fait rêver tant de papilles cinéphiles...

Comment: Pardon...le bas-peuple? Par rapport à quoi, "le haut peuple". Quel language.

Answer (score 6):

L'origine de la soupe vient de ce qu'est une soupe : une tranche de pain.

Quant au potage, il vient du pot où sont cuits les légumes.

La soupe est donc par extension un plat complet (potage de légumes parfois cuits avec un bout de lard, ajouté au pain) pour ceux qui n'avaient pas les moyens de consommer de la viande.
Le potage est plutôt une entrée venant avant d'autres plats, donc un mets destiné à une table bien garnie.

Answer (score 0):

Le potage est soumis à une recette précise. La soupe est un savoir-faire régional ou familiale. Le reste n'est que littérature !

Comment: Pouvez-vous donner une référence?