# Qu'est-ce qu'on entend par « Une couille dans le potage, c’est une erreur, deux, c’est une recette » ?

Tags: sens, littérature, vulgarité

Que veut dire Franz Bartelt dans cette phrase, citée dans le livre *Et Puis Paulette* :

> Une couille dans le potage, c’est une erreur, deux, c’est une recette.

Et est-ce que ça a un sens vulgaire ?

Comment: Cette phrase est dans le roman (polar) de Franz Bartelt [*Nadada*](http://www.telerama.fr/livre/franz-bartelt-a-un-ami,36952.php). Bartelt utilise beaucoup l'humour, et aime créer des expressions imagées à l'instar de celle-ci. C'est peut-être la phrase que les critiques ont le plus retenue de ce livre.

Comment: D'une façon générale, le mot « couille » est assez vulgaire. À éviter dans les conversations avec des gens que l'on ne connait pas.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Ça dépend, [celle du pape](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couille_du_pape) n'est pas vulgaire, elle se déguste!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le mot "*couille*" est vulgaire, mais l'expression "*dans le potage*" montre que la "*couille*" n'est pas à sa place, donc cela indique qu'une erreur ou une faute a été commise.

De fait, l'usage du mot "*couille*" pour désigner une erreur vient du monde de l'imprimerie, où l'on appelait toute erreur typographique "***une couille du typographe*",** parce que la plus mémorable de ces "*couilles*" avait été l'omission de la lettre "***q***" dans le mot "***coquille***", ce qui produit effectivement une regrettable erreur...

Ajoutons que, dans l'imprimerie toujours, beaucoup rechignaient à employer le mot "*couille*" en raison de sa vulgarité, aussi l'erreur typographique prit plutôt le nom de "***coquille***".

Answer (score 4):

Je n'ai pas lu le livre et je ne connais pas le contexte dans lequel la phrase a été dite, donc difficile d'interpréter la phrase avec certitude, mais je pense que c'est un jeu de mot basé sur l'expression suivante:

Il y a une couille dans le potage [signifie](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/14093/y-avoir-une-couille-dans-le-potage/) qu'il y a un problème qu'on n'a pas identifié:

> L'expression viendrait de la Vendée où la touille est une cuillère à
>   soupe, qui serait restée dans le potage. Par extension, l'expression
>   est devenue familière, et trouver une couille dans son potage est un
>   problème qui n'est pas identifié.

Si il y en a deux, alors on sort de cette expression et on passe au sens littéral, qui peut être considéré comme étant une recette de cuisine.

Le sens n'est pas vulgaire, mais le niveau de langue l'est.

Comment: À mon avis ça reste encore imagé, *c'est une recette* voulant dire c'est volontaire et peut-être une pratique habituelle, aussi douteuse qu'elle soit. Mais je n'ai pas pris le temps de lire le contexte non plus.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Effectivement, si *c'est une recette* peut signifier *c'est volontaire* (signification que je n'avais jamais entendue jusque-là), cela expliquerait mieux la phrase de Franz. Mon interprétation personnelle vient du monde de la musique où l'on enseigne parfois aux débutants qu'une petit faute est une erreur, une grosse faute est une variante.

Comment: À rapprocher peut-être aussi de la blague qui je pense a dépassé le milieu de la restauration « une mouche dans le potage, c'est un accident, deux c'est une recette » (→ deux le cuisinier l'a fait exprès).

Comment: La figure de style a peut-être aussi été empruntée au fameux dialoguiste Michel Audiard, qui fait dire à Lino Ventura dans "Les Barbouzes": "Un barbu, c'est un barbu. Trois barbus, c'est des barbouzes".