# Le verbe « emmitonner » ?

Tags: étymologie, alimentation, dialectes

Dans un [document](http://www.langue-francaise.org/dlf214.pdf) datant de 2004 (p.20), on parle de *mots en péril* et on donne entre autres le verbe *emmitonner*, qu'on retrouve au [*FEW/Wartburg*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/62/177) et au vieux *Littré* :

> emmitonner (an-mi-to-né) v. a.
>
> *Terme populaire.* Envelopper dans des mitaines les mains, et par suite
>   tout le corps dans quelque étoffe moelleuse.
>
> - *Fig.* Emmitonner quelqu'un, le circonvenir, l'endormir sur ses intérêts.
> - S'emmitonner, v. réfl. S'emmitonner dans une bonne douillette.
>
> HISTORIQUE 
>   XVIe s. "*Tel qui se tient emmitonné dans les martes jusqu'aux
>   aureilles*", [[Montaigne](https://books.google.com/books?id=m69mgNZOhCMC&dq=%22emmitonn%C3%A9%20dans%20les%20martes%22%20montaigne&hl=fr&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q=%22emmitonn%C3%A9%20dans%20les%20martes%22%20montaigne&f=false), I, 259]
>
> ÉTYMOLOGIE
>   En 1, et [mitonner](http://www.littre.org/definition/mitonner).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire Littré*, « [emmitonner](http://www.littre.org/definition/emmitonner) » ]

L'emploi populaire fait penser à un embaumement. On a aussi le sens au figuré *circonvenir*, *endormir*. La référence étymologique au *Littré* est curieuse ; *mitonner* (16<sup>e</sup>) vient de [mitonnée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitonn%C3%A9e), et c'est le sens culinaire du terroir Normand de *longuement mijoté*, avec l'idée du *miton* (dérivé de *mie*), le morceau de pain. Il y a ensuite une extension de sens de mitonner vers le figuré pour la *préparation délicate* d'une chose, puis au 17<sup>e</sup> suivent aussi l'application aux personnes et la forme pronominale (*DHLF/Rey*) de (se) mitonner. Je ne vois pas le lien avec *envelopper dans des mitaines les mains*, comme dans Montainge, et c'est le verbe *mitonner*.

C'est qu'on a aussi un tout autre sens pour [miton](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/miton), celui de la manchette, du gant ; dérivé de la [*mite*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXmggj;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s171512f8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) (aussi [*FEW/Wartburg*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/62/175)). On a la [*mitaine*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitaine), de cette ancienne *mite*, et, par allusion, la fourrure. On a aussi la [moufle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moufle/1), ce gant épais ; on note qu'une *mitaine* au sens ancien (gant sans séparation sauf pour le pouce) est une *moufle* en France depuis 1718 (par déduction vu la spécialisation de mitaine pour le gant dont les phalanges sont découvertes à compter de cette date, *DHLF/Rey* ; *contra* Canada, mitaine = moufle). Cette deuxième a joué sur la première, et on a déjà eu cette altération, la [mitoufle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitoufle) (16<sup>e</sup>) ; on dit aussi que *mitouflé* provient d'un croisement de *mitaine* et *emmouflé*. La *mitoufle* est disparue mais nous a laissé le verbe [**emmitoufler**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/emmitoufler). On a aussi [*mitainé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitain%C3%A9) pour qui porte des mitaines, mais on n'a jamais eu *emmitainer* ; c'est bien *emmitonner*.

---

Au final *emmitoufler*, dont le substantif (*mitoufle*) voulant dire mitaine/moufle est disparu, s'est imposé sur *emmoufler* et *emmitonner*, disparus, dont les substantifs sont usuels (mitaine/moufle) ; le tout élaboré semble-t-il initialement à partir de l'idée de mettre des mitaines/moufles...

---

- Peut-on confirmer cette étymologie ? De quel *miton* s'agit-il dans *emmitonner* : est-ce une extension de la *soupe*, ou de la *mitaine* ?
- Le verbe *emmitonner* est-il vraiment disparu ?
- Le cas échéant, est-ce donc pour ainsi dire la marmite normande ([*mitonnée*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mitonner%2Cmitonn%C3%A9e&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmitonner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmitonn%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0))
  qui est *responsable*, par trop forte compétition, non pas de
  l'étymologie d'*emmitonner* (pour *emmitoufler*) comme on l'affirmait au
  *Littré*, mais plutôt de sa disparition ? Est-ce généralement l'exemple d'une manifestation de l'empire de l'art culinaire sur la langue française ?

Answer (score 1):

*Emmitonner*<sup>1</sup> ? Première rencontre : 
 *emmi-* donne l’idée de mettre *en* (dedans) et *mi* (au mi-lieu), *mitonner* donne l’idée d’une préparation culinaire longue, soigneuse et douce à la fois, comme une *[soupe](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-potage-et-soupe)* surveillée de temps en temps sur un des coins les plus tempérés d’une antique *[cuisinière à bois](https://www.qwant.com/?q=cuisini%C3%A8re%20%C3%A0%20bois%20ancienne&t=images)*, près de laquelle il fait bon se tenir l’hiver, et donc l’idée, comme dans *emmitoufler*, de se tenir au chaud dans une chaleur bienfaisante, confortable qui devient lénifiante en affaires : dans ces situations on se détend, on baisse sa garde.

Que selon les patois et usages régionaux, on soit parti de *soupe* ou de *mitaine*, deux moyens de lutter contre le froid, qu’il y ait eu des échanges, des assonances, des jeux de phonèmes, il n’y a plus d’oreilles pour saisir ces évolutions qui fluctuent dans l’oralité.

Mais la question demeure intéressante.
Il y a dans quelques-uns de mes neurones, une saveur dans *emmitonné* (peut-être une nostalgie des mots oubliés) qui me ferait pencher pour *soupe* alors que logiquement *mitaine* me séduit.

Il y a quelque part dans *emmitoufler* (dans des vêtements et donc de mitaine) l'idée d'une protection contre le souffle [de l'hiver] donc à l'extérieur, et dans *emmitonner* l'idée de coin chaleureux des maisons d'autrefois : dans la cuisine (préparation mitonnée) ou sous la couette.

... mais tout cela n'a rien d'académique, seulement une perception de la musique des mots... qui peut avoir d'autres interprétations.

On ne voit pas les gens *emmitonnés* (*cocooning* du IIIe millénaire), car ils sont chez eux, mais on les voit *emmitouflés* (dans des "polaires", qui complètent les *mitaines*).
Ce serait donc l'usage qui privilégie l'un sur l'autre.

---

*<sup>1</sup>Disparu du petit Robert*

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette 1- Il me semble difficile de confirmer l'étymologie, tant ces mots ont eu des accents et des lieux d'expressions différents, et les expressions régionales préférées d'avant guerre se sont uniformisées avec les nouveaux médias. 2- *emmitonner* à disparu (au moins pour 99% des francophones hexagonaux). 3- On ne voit pas les gens *emmitonnés* (cocooning du IIIe millénaire), car ils sont chez eux, mais on les voit *emmitouflés* (dans des "polaires", comme les ours !). Ce serait donc l'usage qui privilégie l'un sur l'autre.