# Comment traduire « nester » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, demande-de-mot

Comment désigner quelqu'un qui aime entretenir sa maison, un espace personnel pour être bien ? Par opposition à quelqu'un qui déménage tous les 4 matins, entre le canapé de l'un et le camping de l'autre sans se soucier d'un habitat permanent.

> [Nester](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nester) :  one that nests
>
> ??? : quelqu'un qui fait son nid

Pour l'instant, ma préférence va à ***sédentaire***, mais j'aimerais trouver mieux, dans la direction "qui aime sa maison" (*fée du logis*, *hôte de maison*, ce genre d'idée).

Comment: I can’t think of how to get a home/house/nest-specific noun out of it, but I see a possible, albeit perhaps slight, connection between the feeling of content satisfaction (w/their surroundings) shared by many “nesters” (especially empty nesters!) and the idea captured by the *dicton*: "Un petit chez soi vaut mieux qu'un grand chez les autres." ... This could give rise to the notions of *content[ement]*, *satisfait/e//satisfaction*, & perhaps even *comblé/e*, but they’d all need extra words to make them “nest”-specific, which a translation of “nester” would require (and which I can't think of).

Comment: Thanks Papa Poule ! I can feel your pain looking fir words to describe empty nesters !

Answer (score 5):

Ce quelqu'un pourrait être décrit comme un "casanier"

> Qui manifeste le goût de rester chez soi

... ou de "sédentaire"

> Qui sort peu, qui reste ordinairement chez soi

voire de "pantouflard" (un peu péjoratif) !

Comment: J'aime bien sédentaire. Le problème de "casanier", c'est que c'est plutôt "ne pas sortir de chez soi" que "ne pas déplacer son chez-soi", i.e. ne pas bouger *ce soir* que ne pas bouger *dans l'année à venir* (plutôt ce que je veux exprimer, acheter une maison c'est pour du long-terme). Ça s'applique aussi à pantouflard, dans une moindre mesure (qui est effectivement inutilement péjoratif en l'occurence).

Answer (score 4):

On trouve bien usuels et adéquats les mots choisis dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22436)...

---

Par ailleurs on a déniché au *GDT* le mot pour une personne qui a un comportement similaire, le [*coconneur(coconneuse) ou cocouneur(cocouneuse)*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358003) :

> Personne qui aime [coconner](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358004), c'est-à-dire se dorloter, ou se faire
>   dorloter, dans un lieu douillet et protecteur comme un cocon.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique, GDT ]

...donc faire du [*coconnage ou coucounage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358006) (*cocooning*), se prêtant bien à l'analogie avec le nid, et que l'on définit comme le « comportement psychosocial qui se caractérise par une tendance au repli dans le cocon protecteur du domicile que l'on tente de rendre le plus douillet possible ». On explique que le [cocon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/cocon) est basé sur le provençal pour la *coque d'un oeuf*. Au *Larousse* on a *faire du [cocooning](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cocooning/16865)* et aussi le sens *dorloter* pour le verbe *cocooner* avec la graphie avec le double *o*. De sens peut-être plus restreint que ce qu'on décrit en question (cette personne qui aime se faire un nid douillet de son [bercail](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bercail/8829) ; s'[emmitonner](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/15982) ?) car c'est du vocabulaire en psychologie/sociologie. Par ailleurs, on a des emplois du *coconnage* avec le [commerce](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8382615) et l'[automobile](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358005) où l'on réfère au *repli douillet* et à *l'environnement douillet du foyer*.

---

Autrement on a fait allusion à ne pas déménager souvent, à la sédentarité etc. mais la définition de nom *nester* est plutôt laconique à mon avis, le verbe anglais auquel elle renvoie signifiant à première vue [*to settle (in)*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nest#Verb), peut-être comme dans un nid, ou parfois se regrouper, en ce qui a trait aux êtres humains ; oui le nom associé *nest* peut sans doute référer à l'aspect douillet d'une demeure, mais l'existence du [*empty nester*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/empty%20nester) (les parents humains restant après le départ de leur progéniture) me laisse songeur sur l'idée qu'on se fait du terme. Faisant donc abstraction de ce terme ici, on peut aussi cerner avec une locution comme *[s'établir](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_%C3%A9tablir/31241?q=s%27%C3%A9tablir#31170) ou [s'installer](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/settle/610862?q=settle%20in) pour [de bon](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bon/10105/locution?q=pour%20de%20bon#16001648)* ([*à demeure*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/demeure/23299/locution?q=%C3%A0%20demeure#170794) serait sans doute inusité)/*être bien [établi](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_%C3%A9tabli/31240)* ([*établi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tabli) est vieilli dans ce sens de « qui est installé dans un lieu, en vue d'y séjourner pour une période relativement longue »), certains des éléments recherchés, comme (le désir/constat de) la durée. Je ne sais comment faire un nom de celui qui est ancré solidement au terroir du logis ; différemment on a celui qui *a un goût de [terroir](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/terroir/77475/locution?q=terroir#175960), qui sent le terroir* : les origines. Enfin on connaît aussi le nom le [chez-soi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chez-soi) et des adages de type ...*maître [chez](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chez) soi*, et rien n'empêche de concocter *un/une maître(sse) du chez-soi*.

Comment: La réponse pourrait laisser penser que cocooner n'est employé qu'au Québec...  le terme est très employé aussi dans l'hexagone. Voici sur des sites français de France, [Des vêtements d'intérieur pour cocooner avec style](http://bit.ly/2dxRAOy), [10 idées pour cocooner en solo](http://bit.ly/2dxULFX), [20 idées pour buller, rêver et cocooner ce week-end](http://bit.ly/2eiOfpl), etc.

Comment: Intéressant, à défaut d'être usuel. Ça sonne quand même beaucoup comme un anglicisme, dans les liens de Laure ; pour une traduction, c'est dommage.

Comment: ... et puis, comme en témoignent visiblement les liens de @Laure (merci !), c'est employé dans le sens d'aimer être chez soi *ce soir* (comme "casanier"). Je veux plutôt dire "aimer construire son chez soi *pour les 20 années à venir*".