# Le « courtbouillon » est-il un court-bouillon ?

Tags: terminologie, alimentation, régionalismes

Je lis qu'un [*court-bouillon*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/court-bouillon/19960?q=court-bouillon#19851) est un liquide dans lequel on fait cuire du poisson ou des crustacés. Par ailleurs on a le (*catfish/redfish*) ***courtbouillon*** (aussi *couvillion*, *coubion*) [[images](https://www.google.com/search?q=catfish%20redfish%20courtbouillon&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)]  et du (*crawfish*) ***étouffée*** [[images](https://www.google.com/search?q=crawfish%20%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)] de la Louisiane (É.-U.). Ça semble passablement plus élaboré qu'un liquide servant à la cuisson ; c'est en fait un mets ou un plat.

---

Est-ce qu'un *court-bouillon* peut désigner aussi un tel plat ou un mets en français ?

Comment: En France, le court-bouillon sert surtout à pocher des poissons (raie), coquillages ou crustacés (écrevisses, langouste...). Mais certains y mettent des lapins (http://www.loeul-et-piriot.com/recette-lapin.php?id_page=19&id_recette=741&PHPSESSID=8a6ca44ae8c74d985495958efc2ee1f5 ) et sûrement d'autres viandes (ce qui donne alors un pot-au-feu) ; dans le nord et la Belgique c'est du *waterzooi* (en principe poisson ou poulet ) -- Votre § *Wikipédia, TLFi, GTD* donne les usages dont j'ai entendu parlé.

Comment: Le court-bouillon sert à parfumer l'eau de cuisson et on ne mange pas (ou alors c'est anecdotique) les légumes qui ont servi a le faire, dans le pot-au-feu ils font partie du plat, et sont même le composant principal, quant au ragoût il servent, la viande prédomine et bouillon est réduit de la plus grande partie de ses liquides

Comment: @cl-r Merci. Exactement, d'où la question, que sans doute je ne réussis pas à exprimer correctement. Leur recette n'est clairement pas celle d'un simple bouillon servant à pocher un truc, c'est plutôt un mets et il y a réduction mais rien n'est drainé. Pourquoi a-t-on employé court-bouillon plutôt que bouillabaisse ou pot-au-feu ? En fait ils ont des recettes où ils emploient les mots bouillabaisse et même fricassée, mais pas ici. J'essaie de comprendre si c'est relié à une compréhension usuelle du sud de la France et quel est le terme le plus associé à ce type de plat de poisson...

Comment: La bouillabaisse (originaire de la Grèce, Marseille étant à l'origine une cité phocéenne) est une *soupe* ( http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2242/848 ) de poisson à cause du pain que l'on ajoute, c'est un plat régional typé. Elle s'appelle *Chaudrée* en Charente-Maritime et en Vendée (elle est moins épicée : ce ne sont pas les mêmes climats, ni les mêmes mers). Chaque région interprète les termes culinaire selon son histoire. La différence entre ragoût, fricassée (on ajoute de la crème??), pot-au-feu est assez récente.

Comment: @cl-r Merci, encore fort intéressant. Vous avez assurément le matériel pour répondre même brièvement. Il se peut qu'une bonne réponse ne réussisse pas à répondre de la manière que je souhaite et que seules quelques lignes bien senties soient nécessaires ici. Peut-être que la connaissance du lexique n'est pas directement reliée aux choix qu'on fait, en effet. On a peut-être allongé la sauce de ce qui fut d'abord un court-bouillon, pour ainsi dire. Je ne sais pas. Merci !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Le court-bouillon***. La technique traditionnelle de cuisson, la sauce, et l'effet du *court-bouillon* :

> (A) ... un poisson cuit au court-bouillon était apporté dans un long plat
>   en terre, où (...), infrangible mais contourné encore d'avoir été jeté
>   vivant dans l'eau bouillante (...), il avait l'air d'apparaître dans
>   une céramique de Bernard Palissy. (Proust)
>
> (B) Un dîner de gourmet, où une poularde (...) a pour sauce ce
>   court-bouillon de volaille où flottent des truffes (Goncourt).
>
> (C) LE CHEVALIER. − (...). Je n'aime la truite qu'au [bleu](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Livre_de_cuisine/Truite_au_bleu). (...). Voyons!
>   C'est bien au bleu qu'on les jette vivantes dans le court-bouillon?
>   AUGUSTE. − Justement, seigneur. LE CHEVALIER. − Et qu'elles gardent
>   leur saveur, leur chair, parce que l'eau bouillante les a surprises?
>   (Giraudoux)
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé - TLFi ex. tirés de
>   *court-bouillon* ]

On parle surtout d'un *liquide servant à la cuisson par pochage*, [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court-bouillon), [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/Court-bouillon), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8355315) ; « décoction épicée et aromatisée, parfois vinaigrée ou additionnée de vin, servant principalement à cuire le poisson et les crustacés, mais également à cuisiner les abats blancs. [...] », *Le grand Larousse gastronomique*. On a même l'emploi par métonymie : Plat préparé au court-bouillon. *Court-bouillon de saumon*. (TLFi). On parle aussi dans certains cas d'[étouffade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/estouffade) et de [daube](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/daube), mais essentiellement pour le boeuf et le voeu ; on dit à la limite pour le thon avec la daube. (LgLg)

---

**Le *courtbouillon* & l'*étouffée***. Contrairement à ce qu'on entend généralement du terme en français, c'est apparenté à l'« [étouffée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e) (d'écrevisses) » en français de [Louisiane](http://www.lsu.edu/hss/french/undergraduate_program/cajun_french/cajun_french_english_glossary.php) (dit Wikipédia ; voir aussi glossaire [cadien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadiens)-anglais LSU : étouffée (n.f.) *style of cooking in which the food is "smothered" [[généralement](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/smother) cuire dans une sauce riche] by being cooked while covered. étouffée d'écrevisse crawfish étouffee or smothered crawfish* ; voir aussi [AHDofEL](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=etouffee&submit.x=0&submit.y=0).).<sup>1</sup> Dans une [recette](http://www.jfolse.com/recipes/seafood/fish29.htm) de *courtbouillon*, on fait référence à son ancêtre du sud de la France comme étant une « *soup* » ; dans une [autre](http://www.nolacuisine.com/2005/10/29/cajun-catfish-courtbouillon-recipe/), on le qualifie de « *stew* » ([ragoût](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rago%C3%BBt)).<sup>2</sup> Les tomates y sont bien représentées. Par ailleurs, même si généralement on a le court-bouillon comme liquide servant à [pocher](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pocher), « [c]uire dans un liquide (eau, court-bouillon, vin...) en maintenant la cuisson proche de l'ébullition. » (TLFi), cette technique n'est pas exactement celle des recettes qui parlent plutôt d'amener à ébullition avant de faire mijoter à feu doux... En ce sens la [bouillabaisse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouillabaisse) ne cadre pas exactement en termes de cuisson (on parle d'ébullition constante et courte), malgré ses tomates et son [étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bouillabaisse)...

---

**R**: Donc non, le *court-bouillon* par métonymie réfère surtout à la technique de cuisson. Par ailleurs il y a tout un lexique pour désigner des mets similaires au courtbouillon de Louisiane, comme bouillabaisse ou fricassée (voir note 2, plus bas).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>  Une *étouffée* ressemble à un emploi par métonymie, comme avec *court-bouillon de saumon* pour *saumon (cuit) au court-bouillon*, mais il ne s'agit pas plus de cuisson à la vapeur que de pochage ici. Plus généralement en français, on a *étouffée* en [adjectif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e/2), comme dans « *[l]onge de veau étouffée*. Cuite à l'étouffée. »  (*carpe a l'estouffee* 1393, TLFi) et *LgLg* dit uniquement *à l'étouffée*, surtout avec cuire, et le dresse en synonyme d'[étuver](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tuver) en disant « La cuisson à l'étuvée (ou à l'étouffée) [...] » (LgLg, *étuver*). Le [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e/31513) en ligne fait référence à la Louisiane pour une étouffée, mais uniquement pour parler d'une sauce sans [roux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roux) alors qu'il fait peu de doutes que le courtbouillon de Louisiane contienne du roux brun (un mélange de farine et de gras/beurre, selon les traditions ; par exemple en blond, une base de [*béchamel*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A9chamel/8567?q=b%C3%A9chamel#8513)). Ainsi non seulement l'*étouffée* (écrevisse, crevettes) ne semble pas être directement reliée à la cuisson *à l'étouffée* ; mais elle ne correspondrait pas non plus exactement au *courtbouillon* traditionnel au roux et aux tomates avec barbotte ou sébaste (perche, rascasse) contrairement à ce que dit Wikipédia ; il s'agirait cependant de variations sur un même thème.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Le courtbouillon semble souvent servi avec/sur du riz, et l'idée de parler d'un ragoût au poisson me semble étrange, mais vu la composition ça m'a fait penser à la [*gibelotte*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8367443) ([2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibelotte)) de Sorel (Québec), soit une sorte de [bouillabaisse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bouillabaisse/10494?q=bouillabaisse#10362) à la [barbotte](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198876) sauf que peut-être d'une consistance davantage similaire à celle d'une [fricassée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fricass%C3%A9e/35234?q=fricass%C3%A9e#35201).</sub>