# La différence entre un potage (une soupe) et une purée ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

J'ai trouvé le post suivant très intéressant: [« potage » et « soupe »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-potage-et-soupe)  concernant la soupe et le potage, mais je me demandais quelle est la différence avec la purée ?

J'ai compris que j'utilisais depuis toujours le mot "soupe" sans sa définition, pensant que c'était une mixture liquide de légumes ou d'un légume mixé. Donc j'orienterais ma question plutôt en demandant la différence entre potage et [purée](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/puree) ?

Comment: Je mange le potage avec une cuillère (je pourrais le boire à la rigueur) mais je ne pourrais pas le manger avec une fourchette. Par contre si je ne mange pas la purée avec les doigts je préfère utiliser une fourchette (même si en cas de besoin une cuillère pourrait faire l'affaire).

Answer (score 4):

Voici les premières différences qui me viennent à l'esprit, même si elles ne sont pas  discriminantes à 100%.

1. Quand on parle de purée sans en indiquer la composition, il s'agit par défaut de purée de pommes de terre. Sinon, une purée est souvent à base d'un seul ingrédient (purée de pois, de tomates, de carottes, de marrons, etc.) alors que les soupes ont très souvent des ingrédients variés.
2. Les soupes/potages/consommés sont assez ou très liquides, si on penche une assiette en contenant, elle va sûrement se vider sur la table alors que si on fait la même expérience avec de la purée, il y a de bonnes chances pour qu'elle reste dans l'assiette, ou au moins qu'elle ne s'en détache que très lentement. Il s'agit donc là d'une différence de viscosité.
3. Si on écrase un légume ou un fruit sans le faire cuire, le résultat ne s'appellera pas soupe/potage/consommé (à l'exception du gazpacho et autres rares soupes crues). Par exemple le guacamole est une purée d'avocat mais pas une soupe d'avocat.

Comment: Il n'y a donc pas de limites définies je suppose... Par exemple il m'arrive souvent de faire "une purée" chourave + patate. Ou de faire des "soupes" qui ont la même consistance qu'une purée mais avec 4/5 légumes différents. Seul la consistance et le nombre d'ingrédient définissent si c'est une purée ou non ?

Comment: Oui, il n'y a pas de frontière franche entre purée et soupe, il y a un certain recouvrement pour certaines préparations en effet.

Comment: Ne pourrait-on pas dire que  la frontière se situe entre la fourchette et la cuillère ?

Comment: @None Oui, très juste. C'est un peu ce que je voulais dire avec l'image de l'assiette penchée et de son contenu.

Answer (score 0):

À mon avis une différence fondamentale d'avec la [soupe](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2399987) et le [potage](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8432180), c'est la fonction : une *purée* n'est pas servie en lieu et place et ne remplace pas une *soupe* ou un *potage* etc. dans un repas parce qu'une *purée* est aussi une [*préparation*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8888017), davantage qu'un mets seul il me semble. Tel un accompagnement et comme on l'a dit [dans une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45314) bien des locuteurs pensent d'abord à la *purée de pomme de terre*, mais vu un régionalisme je suis plus familier avec les [*patates pilées*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2497119), peu recommandables pour la ligne et donc j'associe encore davantage la *purée* aux fruits, comme la [*compote de pommes*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2076603), voire à la nourriture pour bébé, que j'adore, qu'aux légumes mais tout de même. Par ailleurs une *purée* peut certainement servir à préparer une une [trempette](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502291) et souvent dans un potage pourrait-on dire que l'ingrédient comme le légume est [*en purée*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pur%C3%A9e).

Comment: Exactement... je mets du beurre et du lait, des herbes salées du bas-du-Fleuve et peut-être un peu de ciboulette, souvent j'ai déjà mis un oignon là-dedans... bien oui autrement je trouve ça sec. Bien finalement c'est peut-être plus qu'une différence de mots, la réponse est vraiment assez subjective et je suis loin d'être une référence en cuisine hahaha. @vc74

Comment: @vc74 Surprenant de lire qu'en France métropolitaine la plat  plat est typiquement servit aux malades ! Je cuisine pas mal, et j'ai mangé dans des cantines aussi, la purée est un plat fréquent pour travailleurs en besoin de calories. Par contre la soupe (du moins certaines formes de soupes se rapprochant du potage, c'est plutôt pour les malades et les convalescents !